# Push object's contents into an array

Tags: javascript

I want to push the bottom object's contents into an array, like so:

```
var userArray = [{"xp":200,"level":3,"name":"User 1"},{"xp":300,"level":3,"name":"User 2"},{"xp":100,"level":3,"name":"User 3"},]
```

However, every time I try to use a for loop to do `userArray.push(i)`, and push it into `userArray`, it returns `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

```
{
    "1293818383": {
        "xp": 200,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 1"
    },
    "235489445527289867": {
        "xp": 300,
        "level": 1,
        "name": "User 2"
    },
    "123189273132": {
        "xp": 100,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 3"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those are JavaScript objects.  JSON is a string.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: "every time I try to use a for loop to do " add your code plz How would we know what is `i` in `userArray.push(i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which will return an array of a object's own enumerable property values,

```js
var x = {
  "1293818383": {
    "xp": 200,
    "level": 3,
    "name": "User 1"
  },
  "235489445527289867": {
    "xp": 300,
    "level": 1,
    "name": "User 2"
  },
  "123189273132": {
    "xp": 100,
    "level": 3,
    "name": "User 3"
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

**@etanc**, please have a look at below code.

```
var json_obj = {
    "1293818383": {
        "xp": 200,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 1"
    },
    "235489445527289867": {
        "xp": 300,
        "level": 1,
        "name": "User 2"
    },
    "123189273132": {
        "xp": 100,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 3"
    }
}

var arr = [];
for(var key in json_obj) {
   arr.push(json_obj[key])
}

console.log(arr)
/*
 [{ xp: 200, level: 3, name: 'User 1' },
  { xp: 300, level: 1, name: 'User 2' },
  { xp: 100, level: 3, name: 'User 3' } ]
*/
```

If your data is huge then you won't be able look properly into the data until and unless you don't format it. Use **JSON.stringify()** to format the above o/p to view it in pretty form as follows.

```
JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4);
/*
[
    {
        "xp": 200,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 1"
    },
    {
        "xp": 300,
        "level": 1,
        "name": "User 2"
    },
    {
        "xp": 100,
        "level": 3,
        "name": "User 3"
    }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON into a JS object to start. Then you can loop over the object.

```
// initial js object 
let initial = {"1293818383": {"xp": 200,"level": 3,"name": "User 1"}, "235489445527289867": {"xp": 300, "level": 1, "name": "User 2"}, "123189273132": {  "xp": 100, "level": 3, "name": "User 3" }
    }

// convert object to json -- THIS IS START OF QUESTION
let json = JSON.stringify(initial)

// intantiate userArray
var userArray = []

// parse json into js object
var parsed = JSON.parse(json)

for (let obj in parsed){
// use each key of object to get value
  userArray.push(parsed[obj])
}
console.log(userArray)
// [ { xp: 200, level: 3, name: 'User 1' }, { xp: 300, level: 1, name: 'User 2' }, { xp: 100, level: 3, name: 'User 3' } ]
```